# Android tablet as second sceen in ElementaryOS

Tags: display, desktop, monitors

Does anybody know how to use an Android tablet as a second monitor in ElementaryOS (for extending my desktop)? I know that this should be possible in Ubuntu using one of the latest versions of Gnome but I am not sure if in ElementaryOS can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display) might provide you with some options to try out. As elementary is basically Ubuntu there is a good chance for things working on Ubuntu to work on elementary, too.